# Как сделать анимацию по кругу?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать анимацию, чтобы объект двигался по гругу?

`RotateAnimation` не подходит так как объект вертится вокруг себя.
Нужно добиться имено того чтобы объект сохранял свой вид и двигался по экрану по круговой траектории.

Comment: Сделайте прозрачный квадрат с обьектом на периферии и крутите его. Вопрос что за обьект у вас, конечно.

Comment: А можно немного подробней? У меня картинка ImageView, которая и должна по экрану передвигаться по круговой траектории.

Comment: Если возьмем что-то типа такого: http://irecommend.ru/sites/default/files/product-images/86755/rTcp1hZ23Fnrvs28bsS0qQ.png , поставим точку вращения по центру черного круга, то перефирийные обьекты будут летать как по орбите.

Comment: Немного не то, например картинка если смайлик, то при повороте смайлик будет поворачиватся верхтормашками. Но хотя если сделать две отдельные анимации например, например чтобы смайлик крутился в одну сторону а фон другую, то может получиться. Спасибо, есть над чем подумать

Comment: https://github.com/iglaweb/Ferris-Wheel вот тут есть анимация которая вам нужна, можете покопать.